# Get memory limit in docker file?

Tags: java, docker

Is it possible to get the max memory of a docker container at runtime?

What I want to achieve is:

```
docker run --memory "100m"
```

and access the max memory in the docker file:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Xmx$memory", "-jar", "helloworld.jar"]
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594575/automatically-configure-java-to-use-the-maximum-ram-allocated-to-its-docker-cont

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think you can specify memory constraints in the Dockerfile yet. So the way to do it is to override your `entrypoint` at the command line:

```
$ docker run -i -t --memory "100m" --entrypoint "java -Xmx`cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes` -jar helloworld.jar" example/java-hello
```