# Automatically configure Java to use the maximum RAM allocated to its Docker container

Tags: java, bash, docker

If I do `docker run --memory=X` to run a Java app through a Bash script, is there any way to get this Bash script to **reliably infer** how much memory has been allocated to the container? Basically, I want this Bash script to do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# (Do some other stuff...)

MAX_RAM="$(get-max-ram)"
exec java "-Xms${MAX_RAM}" "-Xmx${MAX_RAM}" -jar my_jar.jar
```

Also, if I do the above, should I make Java use a little bit less than the maximum RAM?

Comment: Don't forget about PermSize ;) (Then don't use maximum RAM..)

Comment: @Gaël permsize is irrelevant since Java 8.

Comment: Indeed, depends on your Java version. Thanks for this precision.

Comment: Good point, thanks! I'm using Java 7, btw.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012023/get-memory-limit-in-docker-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Docker uses [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) to implement resource limits. Inside the container, you can use the [`cgget`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cgget) utility, to print parameters of various subsystems (in this instance, the `memory` subsystem).

For example, consider a container started with a memory limit of 64G (it's Java, after all):

```
> docker run --memory=64G
```

Within the container, then use `cgget` to read the current value of the `memory.limit_in_bytes` parameter:

```
> cgget -nvr memory.limit_in_bytes /
68719476736
```

Note that you'll probably have to install the `cgget` binary via the container image's package manager first. On Ubuntu, you'll need the `cgroup-bin` package.

You can then use this value to dynamically compute your JVM parameters (just as an example, adjust to your own needs):

```
MAX_RAM=$(cgget -nvr memory.limit_in_bytes /)
JVM_MIN_HEAP=$(printf "%.0f" $(echo "${MAX_RAM} * 0.2" | bc))
JVM_MAX_HEAP=$(printf "%.0f" $(echo "${MAX_RAM} * 0.8" | bc))
exec java "-Xms${JVM_MIN_HEAP}" "-Xmx${JVM_MAX_HEAP}" -jar my_jar.jar
```

---

**Important**: When run without memory restriction (i.e. without `--memory=X` flag), the `memory.limit_in_bytes` parameter will still have a value, although of the magnitude of around 2^63 - 4096:

```
> cgget -nvr memory.limit_in_bytes /
9223372036854771712
```

Unless you want to start your JVM with a minimum heap space of about 8 EB, your entrypoint script should also consider this case:

```
MAX_RAM=$(cgget -nvr memory.limit_in_bytes /)
if [ $MAX_RAM -le 137438953472 ] ; then
    JVM_MIN_HEAP=$(printf "%.0f" $(echo "${MAX_RAM} * 0.2" | bc))
    JVM_MAX_HEAP=$(printf "%.0f" $(echo "${MAX_RAM} * 0.8" | bc))
else
    JVM_MIN_HEAP=32G
    JVM_MAX_HEAP=128G
fi

exec java "-Xms${JVM_MIN_HEAP}" "-Xmx${JVM_MAX_HEAP}" -jar my_jar.jar
```

Comment: It wasn't called out explicitly in your example. But are you multiplying the max and min to be smaller than the container so that the JVM can handle a OOM situation before the container potentially exits?

Comment: As a fallback I would use the minimum of `limit_in_bytes` from this answer and MemTotal (in kB) from `/proc/meminfo`

Answer (score 3):

- java5/6/7/8u131-: a simple but efffective method, You can use `java -Xmx cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes` (except windows)
- java8u131+ and java9+: `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap` would do the job.
- java 8u191+: `UseContainerSupport` is turned on by default. This feature is backported from java10, but it hasn't been backported to java9 so far.
- java10+: `UseContainerSupport` is turned on by default.

Ref:

- http://royvanrijn.com/blog/2018/05/java-and-docker-memory-limits/
- https://blog.docker.com/2018/04/improved-docker-container-integration-with-java-10/
- https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/java-se-support-for-docker-cpu-and-memory-limits
- http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/03f2bfdcb636/src/hotspot/os/linux/osContainer_linux.cpp