# Kubernetes memory-exceeded crash loop / JNI latest C++ version not working

Tags: java, linux, docker, kubernetes, java-native-interface

I have some java pods running in a kubernetes cluster.

The pods are running a spring-boot app built using JIB, using a custom JNI library

The base image used by JIB is:

```
FROM ubuntu:rolling as server-base
RUN apt update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y openjdk-17-jre
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
COPY --from=build-jni-library /root/jni-build/jni.so /usr/lib/
ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE prod
```

I have a kubernetes deployment of the form:

```yaml
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: app:220f0c29fae873b65daffff5a43409ab0a85e1d2
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 1Gi
            limits:
              memory: 2Gi
          ports:
            - name: rest-api
              containerPort: 8080
```

As my service gets used, the pods start to exceed their memory limit, and restart.

I'm using Java 17 in my docker build - so expect (the newer versions of) Java to respect the docker/kubernetes resource limits set.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51832723/7759514
https://www.royvanrijn.com/blog/2018/05/java-and-docker-memory-limits/

I suspected that these limits may be ignored because I'm using a custom java base docker image - rather than a prebuilt openjdk image, for example;

So I tried using this as my base image for my JIB build

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim as server-base
COPY --from=build-jni-library /root/jni-build/jni.so /usr/lib/
ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE local
```

However, the problem I get using this image is that the JNI library I've developed requires use of a newer STDLib (which is why I originally used a custom java base image, with the latest ubunutu version); I get this error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jni.so: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/jni.so)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the JVM has been aware of containers since Java 11. It will  only ever use a certain percentage of the memory limit you configured. And by default that is not even 100%.

I fear that what you are seeing is memory leaks (or unbounded memory usage) in the native part of your application. You should be able to confirm this by periodically using `jcmd` to inspect the memory use of your running Java application, or taking heap dumps.

The final question is caused by your build environment containing a newer glibc than the openjdk:17-jdk-slim image. Easily fixed by building in a container with the same base OS.

Comment: `Easily fixed by building in a container with the same base OS.` what do you mean by this?

Comment: I was also suspecting it was a memory leak issue, from JNI, so I tested the exact same scenario (which reproduces the crash) on my local machine, and the memory footprint was expectedly staying platueing - rather than constantly going up, leading to a crash.

Comment: I've been doing some testing, and when I run the app directly on my machine it works fine, however, when I run the app as a docker image on my machine (with 8gb memory limit) I get out of memory errors (the crashing seems to have fixed, I lowered my memory limits for the app in kubernetes

Comment: https://prnt.sc/pqa-TkRR-G68 memory profile running my application locally - not within docker